# applanix_driver stack for Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the applanix_driver stack available for fuerte?
I know the wiki says it is, but I can't find it using aptitude.
The github repository contains only an electric branch, which is not working with fuerte since the python structure has changed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54724/applanix_driver-stack-for-fuerte/) by [BenS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4164/bens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-02-08**:
We'll check the builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have updated our public github to include the fuerte and triggered the builds. It should work for you now. Thanks for the heads-up!

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1